# How to not include page titles in the webform included email values?

Tags: webforms

My webform has pages and sections in a webform. The title of the page is not printed out on screen, but it is printed out in the email. The page name was setup as being the same as the section resulting in the email sent having duplicate headings as follows

[image]

The form has pages and sections with the form build looking like

[image]

I'm using a twig template to print out the results. I could print out each field/title individually however I'd rather just use the 'included email values' functionality. This would make my webform more maintainable. The headings are not in the list of included email values.

[image]

Is there a way to manage the headings using this interface? An alternative would be to use inline css on the email. e.g. .x_webform-section-wrapper > h2 {display:none}. I'm not sure all the downstream applications will cope with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be as easy as changing the wizard page's display settings, but you found a bug.

[Issue #3106037: Allow a multi-step wizard page's display to be customized](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3106037)

Once you apply the patch, in the page element's 'Advanced' you can change how the page is displayed via HTML and text. You can use Twig to just render the child element.

Comment: This issue has been fixed. Please download the latest dev release to review.

Answer (score 0):

I made the label for the wizard page non-breaking-space `&nbsp;`. It is ugly but it works. Luckily we didn't need the page headings.